# Jms : Java messaging service

Tags: jms

Can we use jms to communicate between two applications running on different hosts?
If yes, what configurations have to be done in both applications to make them eligible for communicating each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note JMS is an API specification only. You will need a product that implements the JMS specification for two (or more) applications to communicate. There are number of products that implement JMS specification, IBM MQ, Tibco, Active MQ to name a few.